# unable to figure out error from passport-custom

Tags: node.js, passport.js

trying to use passport-custom and the very first line, from pseudocode at npmjs, errors out:

```
import passportCustom from 'passport-custom';
```

The is no default import in index.js when I open it up under  node_modules/passport-custom/lib
I must be missing something fundamental here, don't know what though

Answer (score 0):

Try to use CommonJS `const passportCustom = require("passport-custom")` You probably have older version of Node.js which does not support ES6 modules.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default export. So you will have to name the items you want to import (put them in curly braces).

```
//Example:
import { a,b,c,d} from 'youPackage';

//Your case:
import { passportCustom } from 'passport-custom';
```

Above are called **named** imports. When a package exports one item by default using: `export default passportCustom ;`, you could have use your code. You can access the code of the package to have a look for yourself.